# AngularJS - Image loading AJAX have different width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat, AJAX, and pagination to load a table in AngularJS.

Here's the code :

```
<ul class="result_panel">
            <li class="result_row" dir-paginate="data in ctrl.datas | itemsPerPage: ctrl.datasPerPage" total-items="ctrl.totalDatas" current-page="ctrl.currentPage">
                <div>
                    <img ng-src="{{ data.url }}" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
                    <div>{{ data.name }}></div>
                </div>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Although it is working like 50% of the time, the other half the time the images won't respect the width and height in CSS. I added inline style in case, but it doesn't change anything.

Also, images are **sometimes** broken link, even though they're only a placeholder. The link is a laravel's route that displays it. If I open a broken link in a new tab, it'll load fine.

A thing to note is that when I paginate to page 2 and images have various width, and if I then paginate to page 3, and then back to page 2, **every single** image will have the right CSS and will load fine.

How can I fix that ?

**UPDATE** :

Found the answer as for images not loading properly. It seems the Laravel session was lost during the process of executing too many AJAX requests, I had to change session.php driver, and .env driver to cookie.

I also have found that the CSS problem disappears in Firefox. But it remains the same in Chrome :(

Comment: Please create a demo that replicates problem. There is nothing in code shown that would cause issues unless whatever  pagination directive you use doesn't honor transclusion

Comment: I can't, the code is too complicated to get replicated, and it's still on a developpment server.
The environnment is Laravel 5, I can post code from it. I thought it was all about AngularJS since the informations contained in the JSON response are all fine, and they're even properly loaded in the page.
The images are displaying as broken links tho, and the CSS is wrong most of the time.
So I figured it's a client side problem...

Comment: Nothing preventing you creating a scaled down version with sample data

Comment: I have troubles recreating this situation on a Plunker. I have updates though, it seems the CSS problem disappears on Firefox, but there are still broken links.
When I go into network tab, I see two "Whoops, something went wrong" Laravel errors. But nothing more showed...